# Unique and Sparse Schema-level Index MongoDB and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, unique-index, mongodb-indexes

I am trying to create an index on two fields of a schema that are to be unique and sparse in MongoDB using Mongoose as follows:

```
var ArraySchema = new Schema ({
    user_id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
    event_id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Event'}
}, {_id:false});

ListSchema.index({user_id:1, event_id:1}, {sparse:true, unique:true});
```

Which is then used in an array in the User schema as such:

```
var User = new Schema({
    arrayType1 : {
        type: [ArraySchema]
    },
    arrayType2 : {
        type: [ArraySchema]
    },
    arrayType3 : {
        type: [ArraySchema]
    }
    //More specifications for user schema...
});
```

However, when trying to save multiple users without the `array` field, errors are thrown for duplicate fields. The error in Mocha looks similar to this: `array.event_id_1 dup key {null, null}`.  An example of a segment of code that would throw this error is as follows:

```
var user1, user2;

user1 = new User({
    username : 'username1',
    password : 'password'
});

user2 = new User({
    username : 'username2',
    password : 'password'
});

user1.save(function() {
    user2.save();
});
```

Here is my reasoning behind making the the fields of ArraySchema unique and sparse: If the `array` field is specifed, I do not want the array to contain duplicate objects; however, the `array` field is not required, so there will be many Users that have `null` for this field.  Obviously I cannot use field-level indices since there are multiple fields that would need an index (`arrayType1`, `arrayType2`, `arrayType3`).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that doing this sort of thing is not supported, at least at this time.  The alternative would be to create a compound index on these fields then whenever adding a new element to the field use `user.arrayType1.addToSet()`.  Here is an example of how this would work:

**ArraySchema:**

```
var ArraySchema = new Schema ({
     user_id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
     event_id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Event'}
}, {_id:false});

ListSchema.index({user_id:1, event_id:1});
```

**User schema:**

```
var User = new Schema({
    arrayType1 : {
        type: [ArraySchema]
    },
     arrayType2 : {
         type: [ArraySchema]
    },
    arrayType3 : {
        type: [ArraySchema]
    }
    //More specifications for user schema...
});
```

Then I could declare new users as usual (as I did in the question); however, when I want to add a new element to `arrayType1`, for example, I would use the following line of code to add to new element **only** if it is not already there:

```
user.arrayType1.addToSet({user_id : user2._id, event_id : event._id});
user.save(function(err, result) {
    //Callback logic.
};
```

Where `user2` and `event` are defined earlier in the code and saved to the db.  Alternatively I could use Mongoose's update function as such:

```
User.update({_id : user._id}, {
        $addToSet : {
            arrayType1 : {
                user_id : user2._id,
                event_id : event._id
            }
        }
    }, function(err) {
        //Callback logic.
    }
);
```

Comment: it was my answer too :)